# Performance optimization of DataFrame based application

Tags: performance, optimization, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm writing an application, which produces several files storing them back to S3.

Most of the transformations operate on DataFrames. The current state of the application is already somewhat complex being translated into 60 jobs, some of them mapped to hundreds of stages. Some of the DataFrames are reused along the way and those are cached.

The problem is performance, which is clearly impacted by dependencies.

I have a few questions, any input on any of them will be highly appreciated.

**(1)** When I split the application into parts, execute them individually reading the inputs from generated files by the previous ones, the total execution time is a fraction (15%) of the execution time of the application run as a whole. This is counterintuitive as the whole application reuses DataFrames already in memory, caching guarantees that no DataFrame is computed more than once and various jobs are executing in parallel wherever possible.

I also noticed that the total number of stages in the latter case is much higher than the first one and I would think they should be comparable. Is there an explanation for this?

**(2)** If the approach with executing parts of the application individually is the way to go then how to enforce the dependencies between the parts to make sure the necessary inputs are ready.

**(3)** I read a few books, which devote some chapters to the execution model and performance analysis through the Spark Web UI. All of them use RDDs and I need DataFrames. Obviously even for DataFrame based applications Spark Web UI provides a lot of useful information but the analysis is much harder. Is there a good resource I could use to help me out?

**(4)** Is there a good example demonstrating how to minimize shuffling by appropriate partitioning of the DataFrame? My attempts so far have been ineffective.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Splitting application is not recommended, if you have more stages and having performance issues then try **Checkpointing** which saves an RDD to a reliable storage system (e.g. HDFS, S3) while forgetting the RDD’s lineage completely.

//set this property in program

```
SparkContext.setCheckpointDir(directory: String) method.
```

//checkpoint RDD

```
RDD.checkpoint()
```

If you are using DataFrames then manually checkpoint the data after logical points by introducing Parquet/ORC hops (Writing & Reading data from Parquet/ORC files)

//Write to ORC

```
dataframe.write.format("orc").save("/tmp/src-dir/tempFile.orc")
```

//where /tmp/src-dir/ is a HDFS directory

//Read ORC

```
val orcRead = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load("/tmp/src-dir/tempFile.orc")
```

2. Spiliting program is not recommended but still if you want to do it then create separate ".scala" programs and apply dependencies at **Oozie** level.

3.In Spark web UI refer SQL tab which will give you the execuiton plan. For detailed study on dataframes run

```
DF.explain() //which will show you the execution plan
```

DataFrames in Spark have their execution automatically optimized by a query optimizer. Before any computation on a DataFrame starts, the Catalyst optimizer compiles the operations that were used to build the DataFrame into a physical plan for execution. Because the optimizer understands the semantics of operations and structure of the data, it can make intelligent decisions to speed up computation.

Refer Spark guide - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

4.Sort the data before any operations such as join. To reduce shuffling use repartition function.

```
DF1 = DF.repartition(10)
```

Please post your code if you have any other specific doubt.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers.  
  
**(1)** DataFrame checkpointing through Parquet/ORC hops definitely helped. It decreased the complexity of DAGs for analysis and the total execution time.

Comment: **(4)** My initial goal was to reduce the number of stages by repartitioning DataFrames logically by the content of the specified field.
Thus groupBy or join on the fields including the one used for repartitioning would not cause wide dependency. That doesn't seem to work as I thought.

However, I did try decreasing the number of partitions, not by suggested repartitioning but rather by changing the value of the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions property from the default 200.
That seemed to work fine and cut the total execution time by more than half.